# Trouble with Coding a map reducer

Tags: java, input, mapreduce, output, bigdata

I am doing a project for class where I have to code a map reducer to read and output data from a data source. My data source is of the most popular baby boy names of Illinois. I am trying to output the top 5 names for each of the 25 years as listed in my  source. I am using a CSV reader code that I based what I have so far. Here is what I have so far. If someone can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

```
package nameReader;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;

public class nameJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(nameJob.class);
        conf.setJobName("Name Reader");

        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        conf.setMapperClass(boyNameMapper.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(boyNameReducer.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));
        JobClient.runJob(conf);
    }
}
```

Mapper

```
package nameReader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

import java.util.regex.*;

public class boyNameMapper extends MapReduceBase
    implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    private Text Rank = new Text();
    private Text Year = new Text();
    private Text Name = new Text();
    private Text Frequency = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
            OutputCollector<Text, Text> output,
            Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        String line = value.toString();
        CSVReader R = new CSVReader(new StringReader(line));
        String[] ParsedLine = R.readNext();
        R.close();
        /* todo
        * Check for null and number of columns
        */
        Rank.set(ParsedLine[0]);
        Year.set(ParsedLine[1]);
        Name.set(ParsedLine[2]);
        Frequency.set(ParsedLine[3]);
        output.collect(Rank, Year, Name, Frequency);
    }
}
```

Reducer

```
package nameReader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import mrtools.CountMap;
import mrtools.NBest;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class boyNameReducer extends MapReduceBase
    implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
    NBest<Text> Best = new NBest<Text>(3);
    CountMap<Text> Counts= new CountMap<Text>();
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
                    OutputCollector<Text, Text> output,
                    Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

        Counts.clear();
        Counts.countInto(values);

        Best.clear();
        Best.putMap(Counts);
        output.collect(key,new Text(Best.bestEntryCountTSV(",")));

    }
}
```

Comment: your question is very broad. Try narrowing it down a bit, so that there is a more specific problem to solve.